# Script ajax doesn't work properly CODEIGNITER

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table made with Bootstrap in which every row is supposed to open a modal by clicking it and show the details.

I have written a script in Ajax to send JavaScript variable to PHP and it worked, except for one thing: the id that I pass to the modal via POST doesn't change after the first time I click the row.

I really hope someone can help fix this. I've struggled for 4 days without any result.

js/page.js

```
function dettagli_messaggio(id){
  var data = {"id" : id};
  jQuery.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/Prg_stage/index.php/pag_admin/prova',
    method : "post",
    data : data,
    success : function(data){
      $('body').append(data);
      $('#leggimex').modal('toggle');
    },
    error : function(){
      alert("Qualcosa è andato storto");
    }
  });
}
```

/views/prova.html (modal page)

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['id']))
  {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $id=(int)$id;
    $mex=$this->funzioni_admin->apri_messaggio($id);
}

?>
 <div id="leggimex" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="leggimex" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
       <h3>Messaggio da: <?php echo $mex[0]->OggettoMessaggio; ?> <?php echo $id; ?> </h3>
     </div>
     <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body">
       <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Oggetto</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Messaggio</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
     </div>
     <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

/views/adminpage.php

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>" data-target="#leggimex" onclick="dettagli_messaggio(<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>);" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Comment: how do you pass the `id` into function?

Comment: Send all the html / js code, and give me a example of the server response.

Comment: I pass the id through oneclick on the tr.  I put an alert on id before the append funcion and the id was correct in every row that i've clicked

Comment: Please show your table?

Comment: i've put the html and js code

Comment: put console.log(data) on the success method of the ajax call and give us the result

Comment: it displays the code of the modal in prova.php

Comment: i have noticed something

Comment: in the console it's correct but in the actual modal it's not correct why is that?

Comment: how if you disable 'cahce' while ajax request? `$.ajax({ cache: false });`

Comment: where do i have to write that?

Comment: nothing chages. In the console it's correct but when i show the modal the first id that i select never changes, even if i click on another row

Answer (score 0):

Since you get the first row correctly I believe you face the same problem I faced when I use the bootstrap model in table rows. Here is how I fixed my problem, really hope it will fix yours too.

You need to assign a unique id to each row in data-target attribute of the bootstrap model.

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>" data-target="#<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>" onclick="dettagli_messaggio(<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>);" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

Now give the same id to your model too like this

```
 <div id="<?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="leggimex" aria-hidden="true">
```

So the only changes are you need to do is assign unique ids to each model and same matching id in each row to that each row triggers correct model. If this method does not work for you comment below.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand well. Do i have to just change the id's? and how do i call the js function then?

Comment: @Mossin you need to assign unique ids to each row data-target attribute. I use <?php echo $cont_mex[$n]->Id;?> just assuming that i get a unique id from above php echo statement

Comment: understood. I'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your modal contents are iterated not overwrited.
I mean, each time you click the button,new modal contents are appended

 --> btn click1 -> `<div id="leggimex">`

 --> btn click2 -> `<div id="leggimex">` `<div id="leggimex">` 

 --> btn click3 -> `<div id="leggimex">` `<div id="leggimex">` `<div id="leggimex">`.... so on

In your case, create a div like `<div id="modal_response"></div>` inside `<body>` tag and change 
`$('body').append(data);` 
to 
`$('#modal_response').html(data);`

Example :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="modal_response"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url : 'index1.php',
    success:function(res){
        $('#modal_response').html(res);
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    }
});
</script>

</html>
```

And my `index1.php`

```
<?php 

$test = '<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>';


echo $test;
?>
```